# Git: Pulling back clone changes into the master it was cloned from

Tags: git

We have a server with several users, one of which `/home/dev` is a "common" user. All of our original Git working trees are stored in `/home/dev`, and all of these became the master from which we cloned bare repos into `/home/git`. From these bare `/home/git` repos, each user clones them into his own `/home/user` area, and then pulls common updates from and pushes his updates to the bare repos. Ok so far.

But when we cd to `/home/dev/master-repo` (say) and try to do a pull from its bare clone in `/git/master-repo.git` with the command: `git pull /git/master-repo.git`, we get a fatal Git error:

> /git/master-repo.git does not appear to be a git repository.

We could simply delete the `/home/dev/master-repo`, and clone it from its bare repo in `/home/git`. Then `/home/dev` would be just like any other user. But I would like to know why the pull can't recognize the bare clone as a git repository.

Answer (score 1):

```
git pull /git/master-repo.git
```

From your description it sounds as if this path is incorrect. Shouldn't the following be correct?

```
git pull /home/git/master-repo.git
```